# Can't load font using font file name

Tags: c#, fonts

There is font file in Windows folder (Font name is Lucida Sans). I try to load that font using following code but I can't create
the font object

```
        PrivateFontCollection c = new PrivateFontCollection();
        c.AddFontFile("c:\\windows\\LSANSDI.TTF");
        FontFamily fa = c.Families[0]; //This line succeeds
        Font fn = new Font(fa, 10);  //I get Exception here and it says that it does not support Regular style
```

Even if u check all styles using fa.IsStyleAvailable function, I get no style available. What is the use of creating such ttf file which cannot be loaded. How can I use that font? But I can see that font has all styles available when I use in MS Word 
Can anyone provide the solution?

Comment: Have you tried to install the font into windows\fonts and read it from there?

Comment: I don't want to install it in Windows folder. I need to use it temporarily and then discard it

Comment: Regarding your deleted comments below, if you can use WPF libaries in C#, you can get the Font Name and Face Name. You'll need a reference to `System.Windows.Media`. But if that is what you're after, you should probably change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the font is bold AND italic, which means you need to check for (FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic) being available, and create the new Font accordingly.